# Exercise 4 of Chapter 7 in Enderton's Elements of Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, well-orders

Let $<$ be the usual ordering on the set $P$ of positive integers. For $n$ in $P$, let $f(n)$ be the number of distinct prime factors of $n$. Define the binary relation $R$ on $P$ by
$$
mRn \iff [f(m)<f(n)]\lor[f(m)=f(n)\land m<n].
$$
Show that $R$ is a well ordering on $P$.

I would like to know whether my solution is correct or not.

and the following is my solution:

Enderton defined 'partial order' as an irreflexive transitive relation. (He used the strict concept of ordering.)

1. $R$ is irreflexive.

let there is an $m\in P$ such that $mRm$.

then $[f(m)<f(m)]\lor[f(m)=f(m)\land m<m]$.

but $f(m)\nless f(m)$ and $m \nless m$.

therefore $\neg mRm$ for all $m$.

2. $R$ is transitive.

let $mRnRk$.

$mRn$ so that $[f(m)<f(n)]\lor[f(m)=f(n)\land m<n]$.

case 1, $f(m)<f(n)$:

by $nRk$, $f(n)\le f(k)$, therefore $f(m)<f(k)$.

case 2, $[f(m)=f(n)\land m<n]$:

if $f(n)<f(k)$ then the same argument with case 1, $f(m)<f(k)$.

if $f(n)=f(k)\land n<k$ then $f(m)=f(n)=f(k)\land m<n<k$.

therefore $mRk$, which implies transitivity of $R$.

3. $R$ is a linear order i.e. trichotomy holds.

let $\neg mRn \land m \neq n$.

by the trichotomy of $<$,
$$
\begin{align}
\neg mRn & \iff f(n)\le f(m) \land [f(m)\neq f(n) \lor n \le m] (\because\text{De Morgan's law and trichotomy of <})\\
& \iff f(n) < f(m) \lor [f(n) \le f(m) \land n \le m](\because\text{distributive law})\\
& \iff f(n) < f(m) \lor [f(n) = f(m) \land n \le m](\because\text{absorption})\\
& \implies  f(n) < f(m) \lor [f(n) = f(m) \land n < m](\because n\neq m)\\
& \iff nRm.
\end{align}
$$

4. $R$ is well-order on $P$.

take a nonempty set $B\subseteq P$.

then there is a nonempty range $f[\![B]\!]$.

$<$ is a well order on $P$ so we can take a least $m\in f[\![B]\!]$.

then we can define a nonempty subset $S := \lbrace x\in P\mid f(x) = m\rbrace$.

we can take a least $m'\in S$.

claim: $m'$ is the least element of $B$.

take another arbitrary $n\in B$.

$m=f(m')$ and $m$ is the $<$-least of $B$ so that $f(m')\le f(n)$.

if $f(m')<f(n)$ then $m'Rn$.

if $f(m')=f(n)$ then $n\in S$ so that we have $m'\le n$.

therefore $m'$ is the $R$-limit of $B$.

Comment: Looks good to me.